# How to avoid walking on detected traps in Baldurs Gate 3?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Here is a problem I'm facing again and again.

I stroll through a dark corner of the world. Pass a perception skill check and detect a trap.

My party, the bumbling idiots they are, they still have a move command and continue happily on their merry way, walking *right into the trap* and blowing everyone to smithereens.

Now in other similar games (e.g. BG1, BG2, ...) I'd simply hit pause - freeze the action for a sec, tell the party to stop and the thieve to get working on the trap.

Alas, there is no pause button in BG3... How can I avoid the above disaster from occurring?

Comment: You can slam shift+spacebar to enter turn based mode to effectively pause the game and issue new orders. But there is some slight delay in switching if moves are already in progress.

Comment: Plus, it only pauses the party characters -- everything else in the world still moves in normal time, which can lead to some... oddities.

Answer (score 3):

There is no pause, but there is "enter turn based", where you control your characters one by one (switching back and forth if wanted) and then let the "world" take its turn.

Another tip could be to "ungroup" your characters, allowing one to walk through, detect the trap (of fail the perception so you retreat and bring another one in to retry). Then when you discover the trap, you can use a range attack to set it off from a safe distance.

Or just have your tank rush through (maybe with fire resistance, either from lore or a potion/spell) and heal afterwards.